# How to add actions to Conversation Services

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I was checking out the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/develop-app.html#implementing-app-actions) on developing applications for the Conversation Service.

Here, it specifies how actions can be used to carry out actions on the application side. It says *these actions are returned by the dialogs*. But I could not find where in the dialog I can specify actions in the response. A google search for the documentation also did not yield any fruitful results. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have access to dialog nodes for same example. Import workspace to your conversation service to see actions specified in the response

More details here:
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/develop-app.html#setting-up-the-service

[image]

Comment: I don't want to import an existing workspace. I want to create my own (I already have by following the tutorial) and try to create actions in my conversation

Comment: You can pass context from dialog tool to application side and likewise from application to dialog tool. In the dialog node where you input the response,over there you can change it to JSON code and pass the context to trigger an action

Comment: That did it. Thanks! Do you happen to know if its possible to do so on the UI without using the JSON version?

Comment: Also, do you happen to know if there is any documentation for actions?

Comment: Not sure if you are referring to these https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/dialog-methods.html